# Website URL Redirects using mod_rewrite in htaccess for Magento2.1 Bitnami LAMP Stack Not Working

Tags: magento-2.1, url-rewrite, .htaccess, 301-redirect

I wanted to write redirect rules to remove index.php from incoming urls in htaccess.conf file(in my app folder) and replace it with the query params.

I ensured my rewrite rule to be working perfectly in locahost,when it comes to bitnami,no changes.
Even simple rewrite rules are not getting done here.
And No records in error.log.

Steps:

1) I ensured in apache2\conf\httpd.conf mod_rewrite module is enabled.

2) I changed in opt\bitnami\apps\magento\conf\httpd-app.conf for my particular Directory AllowOverride all.

3) In bitnami\apps\magento\conf\htaccess.conf

I have added my rewrite rule

> Options +FollowSymLinks
>
> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index.php?route=.+$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%{QUERY_STRING}\? [R=301,L]

Do suggest and Help me with this issue if I am doing something wrong..I have been spending more than 2 days to solve this issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami developer here. If you modified your httpd-app.conf file to use "AllowOverride all", it is possible you have other ".htaccess" file into the "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs" folder that is overwriting that rewrite rule. If you set to "None" should fixes that issue.

Magento also requires to be configured with the hostnami or IP address of your site. It does not depend on the rewrite rule. Check you already configured the application properly with your domain/IP. https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/magento/#updating-the-ip-address-or-hostname

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you soo much Beltran.Its working now.It was because of AllowOverride all in httpd-app.conf that my file rewrite was not reading.             So adding rewrite rules in bitnami\apps\magento\conf\htaccess.conf is the right concept and right way???